# Unexpected token export when running Terminal App

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This seems like just a normal module and export, not sure what's causing this.

**myES6Module.js**

```
const showCar = () => {
   //...code
}

const drive = () => {
  //...code
};

drive();

export { drive, showCar }
```

What's weird is in **my tests I'm able to import and call these just fine and my tests use them and pass**.  But **when I actually run the drive()** which runs the app by prompting the user for terminal input, I get an error saying:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Proxy.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670:28)`

Why would this resolve just fine for test but not live running of the code?

**Here's how I'm running it**, a **script** in my **package.json**:

```
"start": "node --experimental-modules ./myES6Module.js"
```

so it's when I run `yarn start` I get this.  Otherwise, when I run my tests, drive() outputs to the console just fine.

**if I comment out that exports, my script runs fine**...but of course that breaks my tests which rely on exporting stuff.

**UPDATE**

I'm using `--experimental-modules`

So I tried this since I have babel-cli installed:

```
"start": "babel ./myES6Module.js"
```

package.json has the following babel packages:

`"@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.51",`

but that just console.logged the file content, it didn't run it.
**I don't want to use `--experimental-modules` either.** I don't want to change my file extension so how do I get this running?

I took a look at this and it mentions about migrating if you are already using babel-node but is that the only way?

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/v7-migration

Comment: I think this might have already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296667/getting-unexpected-token-export

Comment: yea but `--experimental-modules` is supposed to solve this issue I thought. https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html so that I don't need babel for this

Comment: ah crap the file extension has to be mjs

Comment: I think you're just missing the `.mjs` extension (edit: sorry had the page open, looks like you figured it out :) )

Comment: yea that's it.  So I took out the experimental and tried babel.  I'd like to get this to work now without --experimental-modules

Comment: well I'm using `@babel/register` and yes I do use that to run my mocha tests but trying to use it for my node script, I just tried `"start": "node @babel/register  ./myES6Module.js"`  but that's not quite right

Answer (score 0):

To answer your initial question, you need to have the file extension for the files to be `.mjs` so that you can define in your `package.json` scripts:

```
"start": "node --experimental-modules myES6Module.mjs"
```

The second part about removing the `--experimental-modules` flag as you noted just logged out the file contents when using `babel`. To get around this you can use [`babel-node`](http://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli/#babel-node) but note its warning on use in production. In that warning you will find a link to [Example Node Server w/ Babel](https://github.com/babel/example-node-server) demonstrating a working solution.

To produce the results you are after I've created a minimum working solution with the following which is working for me:

`npm i babel-cli babel-preset-es2015`

Update your `package.json` to:

```
"start": "babel-node --presets es2015 myES6Module.js"
```

And a working `.js` file using `export`:

```
const showCar = () => {
  //...code
}

const drive = () => {
  //...code
  console.log('driving')
};

drive();

export { drive, showCar }
```

**Babel 7**

If you want to use version 7 then try below.

`npm i @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/node @babel/preset-env` so your `package.json` has the below dependencies:

```
"@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
"@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
"@babel/node": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.51"
```

Set the run script to

```
"start": "babel-node myES6Module.js"
```

Create a `.babelrc` file at the root level of your project with

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Now you can execute `npm run start` from the terminal and you should see the output `driving` logged to the terminal based on my example code.

I haven't used version 7 before and the docs say that the `.babelrc` file should use `"presets": ["env"]` but I got an error, however the above and `"presets": ["@babel/env"]` worked the same. Someone else might know the reasoning behind this error I ran into but that's for another question.