# why export is unexpected token while running this code

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am using nodejs 10.13.0. while running this code by using commands on terminal `node --experimental-modules main.mjs` getting an error:

```
(node:3418) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///home/amarjeet/eloquentjs/ch-11%20asynchronous/js/crow-tech.mjs:1
export (function() {
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
   at translators.set (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:33:13)
```

this is `main.mjs` file:

```
 import {bigOak} from "./crow-tech";
 bigOak.readStorage("food caches", caches => {
 let firstCache = caches[0];
 bigOak.readStorage(firstCache, info => {
   console.log(info);
   });
 });
```

this is `crow-tech.mjs` file:

```
  export (function() {
   const connections = [
   "Church Tower-Sportsgrounds", "Church Tower-Big Maple", "Big Maple-Sportsgrounds",
   "Big Maple-Woods", "Big Maple-Fabienne's Garden", "Fabienne's Garden-Woods",
   "Fabienne's Garden-Cow Pasture", "Cow Pasture-Big Oak", "Big Oak-Butcher Shop",
   "Butcher Shop-Tall Poplar", "Tall Poplar-Sportsgrounds", "Tall Poplar-Chateau",
   "Chateau-Great Pine", "Great Pine-Jaques' Farm", "Jaques' Farm-Hawthorn",
   "Great Pine-Hawthorn", "Hawthorn-Gilles' Garden", "Great Pine-Gilles' Garden",
   "Gilles' Garden-Big Oak", "Gilles' Garden-Butcher Shop", "Chateau-Butcher Shop"
   ]
```

// this just comment in js file the code is continued below why is this issue saying that export is undefined token?

```
  function storageFor(name) {
    let storage = Object.create(null)
    storage["food caches"] = ["cache in the oak", "cache in the meadow", "cache under the hedge"]
    storage["cache in the oak"] = "A hollow above the third big branch from the bottom. Several pieces of bread and a pile of acorns."
    storage["cache in the meadow"] = "Buried below the patch of nettles (south side). A dead snake."
    storage["cache under the hedge"] = "Middle of the hedge at Gilles' garden. Marked with a forked twig. Two bottles of beer."
   storage["enemies"] = ["Farmer Jaques' dog", "The butcher", "That one-legged jackdaw", "The boy with the airgun"]
    if (name == "Church Tower" || name == "Hawthorn" || name == "Chateau")
      storage["events on 2017-12-21"] = "Deep snow. Butcher's garbage can fell over. We chased off the ravens from Saint-Vulbas."
    let hash = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++) hash += name.charCodeAt(i)
    for (let y = 1985; y <= 2018; y++) {
     storage[`chicks in ${y}`] = hash % 6
      hash = Math.abs((hash << 2) ^ (hash + y))
    }
   if (name == "Big Oak") storage.scalpel = "Gilles' Garden"
   else if (name == "Gilles' Garden") storage.scalpel = "Woods"
   else if (name == "Woods") storage.scalpel = "Chateau"
   else if (name == "Chateau" || name == "Butcher Shop") storage.scalpel = "Butcher Shop"
   else storage.scalpel = "Big Oak"
   for (let prop of Object.keys(storage)) storage[prop] =  JSON.stringify(storage[prop])
   return storage
   }

  class Network {
   constructor(connections, storageFor) {
    let reachable = Object.create(null)
     for (let [from, to] of connections.map(conn => conn.split("-"))) {
      ;(reachable[from] || (reachable[from] = [])).push(to)
      ;(reachable[to] || (reachable[to] = [])).push(from)
     } 
    this.nodes = Object.create(null)
    for (let name of Object.keys(reachable))
     this.nodes[name] = new Node(name, reachable[name], this, storageFor(name))
     this.types = Object.create(null)
    }

    defineRequestType(name, handler) {
    this.types[name] = handler
    }

    everywhere(f) {
    for (let node of Object.values(this.nodes)) f(node)
     }
    }

    const $storage = Symbol("storage"), $network = Symbol("network")

   function ser(value) {
     return value == null ? null : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))
    }

   class Node {
    constructor(name, neighbors, network, storage) {
    this.name = name
    this.neighbors = neighbors
    this[$network] = network
    this.state = Object.create(null)
    this[$storage] = storage
    }

   send(to, type, message, callback) {
   let toNode = this[$network].nodes[to]
    if (!toNode || !this.neighbors.includes(to))
      return callback(new Error(`${to} is not reachable from ${this.name}`))
     let handler = this[$network].types[type]
     if (!handler)
      return callback(new Error("Unknown request type " + type))
      if (Math.random() > 0.03) setTimeout(() => {
       try {
         handler(toNode, ser(message), this.name, (error, response) => {
          setTimeout(() => callback(error, ser(response)), 10)
           })
          } catch(e) {
          callback(e)
          }
          }, 10 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))
        } 

       readStorage(name, callback) {
       let value = this[$storage][name]
       setTimeout(() => callback(value && JSON.parse(value)), 20)
       }

      writeStorage(name, value, callback) {
      setTimeout(() => {
      this[$storage][name] = JSON.stringify(value)
       callback()
          }, 20)
       }
      }

    let network = new Network(connections, storageFor)
    exports.bigOak = network.nodes["Big Oak"]
    exports.everywhere = network.everywhere.bind(network)
    exports.defineRequestType = network.defineRequestType.bind(network)

     if (typeof __sandbox != "undefined") {
     __sandbox.handleDeps = false
     __sandbox.notify.onLoad = () => {
      // Kludge to make sure some functions are delayed until the
      // nodes have been running for 500ms, to give them a chance to
       // propagate network information.
      let waitFor = Date.now() + 500
      function wrapWaiting(f) {
        return function(...args) {
         let wait = waitFor - Date.now()
         if (wait <= 0) return f(...args)
          return new Promise(ok => setTimeout(ok, wait)).then(() => f(...args))
         }
        }
        for (let n of ["routeRequest", "findInStorage", "chicks"])
        window[n] = wrapWaiting(window[n])
       }
      }

     if (typeof window != "undefined") {
     window.require = name => {
     if (name != "./crow-tech") throw new Error("Crow nests can only require \"./crow-tech\"")
     return exports
      }
     } else if (typeof module != "undefined" && module.exports) {
     module.exports = exports
     }
    })()
```

i dont understand what i am doing wrong! where i am wrong!
i trying this for many hours and dont get into any solution please help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Unexpected Token Export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296667/getting-unexpected-token-export)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only export things with a name, an IIFE has no name:

```
 export const connections = [
  "Church Tower-Sportsgrounds", "Church Tower-Big Maple", "Big Maple-Sportsgrounds",
  "Big Maple-Woods", "Big Maple-Fabienne's Garden", "Fabienne's Garden-Woods",
  "Fabienne's Garden-Cow Pasture", "Cow Pasture-Big Oak", "Big Oak-Butcher Shop",
  "Butcher Shop-Tall Poplar", "Tall Poplar-Sportsgrounds", "Tall Poplar-Chateau",
  "Chateau-Great Pine", "Great Pine-Jaques' Farm", "Jaques' Farm-Hawthorn",
   "Great Pine-Hawthorn", "Hawthorn-Gilles' Garden", "Great Pine-Gilles' Garden",
   "Gilles' Garden-Big Oak", "Gilles' Garden-Butcher Shop", "Chateau-Butcher Shop"
];
```

Comment: but in eloquentjs book they are using IIFE and the things are working. here are the links [crow-tech.js](https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/crow-tech.js) and [this is my main.mjs](https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html#p_qrVbRBjxbB). @JonasWilms

Comment: @amarjeet but they are not exporting it. Also this is not really eloquent, rather ugly.

Comment: @ JonasWilms now the error is ` The requested module './crow-tech' does not provide an export named 'bigOak'

Comment: can you explain me whats that code mean. the downside of this `if (typeof __sandbox != "undefined") {` in [crow-tech.js](https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/crow-tech.js) file. @JonasWilms

Comment: @amarjeet the whole code is badly written, you can't easily rewrite it to module syntax.