# How can I import an ES module in the Node.js REPL in Node 8?

Tags: node.js, import, module

I have an [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) module `right.mjs`. Executing it as a parameter to `node` works well:

```
$ node --version
v8.10.0

$ node --experimental-modules right.mjs
(node:4492) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
executing right module
`executing right module` is the output of the module.
```

In contrast to that, the following input in the REPL waits for further input:

```
$ node --experimental-modules
> (node:4526) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.

> import 'right.mjs';
...
```

I don't understand why.

The same with:

```
> import './right.mjs';
...
```

Trying to `require` results in:

```
> require('./right.mjs');
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /home/xxx/right.mjs
    at Object.Module._extensions..mjs (module.js:686:11)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

So, how can I import an ES module in the Node.js REPL?

Comment: There are REPLs out there which support modules, such as [Replete](https://github.com/jamesdiacono/Replete).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**[This is not currently possible](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/33369)**. ES modules are supposed to be imported from the ES module scope, while REPL isn't considered one. This can improve with time because the support of ES modules is experimental. The use of `require` and `import` is mutually exclusive in the Node.js module implementation, and REPL already uses `require`.

Dynamic `import` is supported in the REPL since Node.js 13. With `node --experimental-repl-await`, it is:

```
await import('./right.mjs');
```

Comment: I believe this is now being tracked in https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/33369

Comment: REPL await is turned on by default as of Node 16.6, and has [a different syntax](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--no-experimental-repl-await) for the feature flag.

Comment: This needs to be updated. `let { date } = await import('quasar')` works fine in Node 18 without any flags.

Comment: Except it's not a static import, so it's not "working fine".

Comment: @BillerBuilder Can you clarify what's the problem with that? Top-level await is supported as well.

Comment: Being able to import ES modules only dynamically (and therefore asynchronously) within the scope of the current module is exactly how the current CJS handles ESM imports. Ergo the current REPL clearly runs in a CJS mode in some sort of async wrapper. Considering REPL is used mostly for checking synchronous code, this can lead to a different unexpected runtime behaviour.

Answer (score 76):

It is possible in Node.js v14, but you need to use the `import` function, rather than the `import` statement.

```
$ node

Welcome to Node.js v14.4.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> let myModule;
undefined
> import("./my-module.js").then(module => { myModule = module });
Promise { <pending> }
> myModule.foo();
"bar"
```

Comment: :( This looks like it still doesn't handle modules containing the `export` keyword

Comment: @hallo it works for me with both named and default exports, but bear in mind you have to access the default export at `module.default`.

Comment: Unfortunately, if your files contain imports that do not have the extension in the filename (`import something from './something';) as most projects do, it will error on you. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The extension is now mandatory: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions - I don't know of a way around that.

Comment: The problem with asynchronous import is solved with `node --experimental-repl-await`. It's `const myModule = await import("./my-module.js")` then. An extension can be omitted with `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` or custom loader (`--experimental-loader`).

Answer (score 44):

With Node.js v16.9.1, which supports top level await, it's even simpler:

```
let { date } = await import('quasar') // module under node_modules, or your own one, etc.
date.getWeekOfYear(new Date())
```

Comment: This is the right answer for Node 18 as well. Should be the accepted answer now but the poster is essentially gone.

Comment: For default imports: 
`const { default: csv } = await import("csvtojson");
await csv().fromString('action,email\nsave,foo@example.com')
`

Answer (score 12):

It is not precisely what was asked about (not really REPL), but (using Node.js 12.6.0), it is possible to execute ESM code from the command line via `--eval`:

1. First, if your ES modules have a *.js* extension instead of *.mjs*, put `"type": "module"` in file *package.json* (see *[Modules: ECMAScript modules, Enabling](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling)*) to allow Node.js treating JavaScript files as modules
2. Run `node --experimental-modules --input-type=module --eval 'code here'`

You could alias this as `esmeval` for example:

`alias esmeval='node --experimental-modules --input-type=module --eval'`

And then you can use it as:

`esmeval 'import { method } from "./path/to/utils.js"; console.log(method("param"))'`

If you can't use Node.js 12 yet as a primary version, but can install via `nvm`, make the alias point to the v12 installation:

`alias esmeval='/c/software/nvm/v12.6.0/node.exe --experimental-modules --input-type=module --eval'`

Comment: Note that implementation of ES modules is changing with node 13 so this might not work in newer versions of node.

Answer (score 0):

Some googling on using a module in the REPL brought me here, and this is what worked for me:

```
npm install -g libphonenumber-js​
node​
> let lib = require('/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/libphonenumber-js')
> lib.isValidPhoneNumber('+97412345678')
false
> lib.isValidPhoneNumber('+15625551234')
true
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with ES modules. Since you are using a `require`, `libphonenumber-js` is loaded as a CJS module which is probably is (?). If I'm correct, this doesn't apply to this question concerning REPL + ESM.