# Run ES6 code in Bash terminal with Bash heredoc

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, ecmascript-6, heredoc

ES5 code can be run easily with Bash heredoc in terminal:

```
node <<HEREDOC
  var fs = require("fs");
  ...
HEREDOC
```

But ES6 code doesn't run, even with the correct --experimental-modules flag:

```
node --experimental-modules <<HEREDOC
  import fs from "fs";
  ...
HEREDOC
```

The error shown is:

```
(node:4130) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
[stdin]:1
import fs from "fs";
       ^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:267:10)
    at Proxy.runInThisContext (vm.js:319:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([stdin]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:30)
    at evalScript (internal/bootstrap/node.js:670:27)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (internal/bootstrap/node.js:340:15)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1098:12)
    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
```

It does show this info "ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental." which means Node.js is running correctly with ES6 module feature, however, **the `import` keyword is just not working**.

**How to run ES6 code inline in terminal with Bash heredoc?** I know I can write the code to file to load as ES6 module normally, but it's a short temporary code, should it be in heredoc better.

Comment: --experimental-modules doesn't support stdin modules (yet), it should do in Node 12.

You could try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm if you really need to ES modules.

Comment: @Jamesernator it does let me import built-in modules only, "npm i moment" doesn't work, "npm i -g moment" doesn't work too

Comment: Yeah only builtin modules work from stdin. There's an open issue for the same problem in the REPL, it's likely the same cause: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/19570

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**:
Since Node.js 14, the flag `--experimental-modules` is no longer needed, it's already by default in Node.js for `.mjs` files, and also for heredoc, but the `--input-type` is still needed on CLI coz ES5 or ES6 is still supposed to be specified for the heredoc:

```sh
node --input-type module <<HEREDOC
  //example:
  import fs from "fs";
HEREDOC
```

**Older guide**:
After looking into it, Node 11 does not support ES modules from stdin at all, if you want to use modules in Node 11 you need to put them in a file.

With Node 12 (currently unreleased but you can try it using `npm i -g node-nightly`), you can use the flag `--entry-type=module` to use stdin as a module.

With `node-nightly` the following worked just fine:

```sh
node-nightly --experimental-modules --entry-type=module <<HEREDOC
  import fs from 'fs'
  console.log(fs);
HEREDOC
```

Edit:

As noted by @Jamesernator in comments, for node-nightly from v13, use "--input-type" instead of "--entry-type".

And only built-in modules are supported, ie. 'import' won't be able to find modules in local dir, and also won't be able to find global modules installed with '-g' flag. Related issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/19570

Comment: that node-nightly is superb! tks

Comment: but latest node-nightly now DOESN'T HAVE option "--entry-type" any more, checked just now with node-nightly v13.0.0-nightly2019042580c0b89bbb. It showed this error: bad option: --entry-type=module

Comment: It has been renamed --input-type a few days ago. You can just use Node 12 now though rather than nightly.

Comment: It might still change though it's an ongoing discussion: https://github.com/nodejs/modules/issues/312

Comment: tks, i can use --input-type now, hope it won't change again.

Comment: it does let me import built-in modules only, "npm i moment" doesn't work, "npm i -g moment" doesn't work too

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question that taught me a lot! Thanks for asking it. Here is what I learned:

**First of all**
Bash heredoc for node is like simply executing node and then typing whatever was typed in heredoc tag

I.E.

```
node --experimental-modules <<HEREDOC
  import fs from "fs";
  ...
HEREDOC
```

is equivalent to

```
node --experimental-modules
> import fs from "fs";
```

And executing node like that opens up the [REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) from node

**Secondly**, the `import` syntax:

```
import fs from "fs"
```

[There is no `fs` in `"fs"`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). That's not an issue for you now, but if the import went through, it wouldn't find that in the `"fs"` module. Instead, what would have been the correct syntax would be, for example:

```
import { readFile } from "fs";
```

This, however, yields:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

**Lastly**, the problem is that the entire feature is, indeed, experimental.

There are opened issues about this:

- [dynamic import can't be used in the REPL](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/19570)
- [How to import an ES module in Node.js REPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54784608/how-to-import-an-es-module-in-node-js-repl)
- [Bug: import() doesn’t work in string input](https://github.com/nodejs/ecmascript-modules/issues/67)

Comment: Just a note in the Node implementation both `import fs from 'fs'` and `import * as fs from 'fs'` do the same thing, the default export for node builtin modules just exports the whole module back.

Comment: @Adelin it does let me import built-in modules only, "npm i moment" doesn't work, "npm i -g moment" doesn't work too