# TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]:

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, ts-node

This is the command i'm trying to run `./bitgo-express --port 3080 --env test --bind localhost` and I'm receiving following error:

```
(node:367854) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
internal/process/esm_loader.js:90
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension "" for /home/root/example.com/BitGoJS/modules/express/bin/bitgo-express
    at Loader.defaultGetFormat [as _getFormat] (internal/modules/esm/get_format.js:65:15)
    at Loader.getFormat (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:116:42)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:247:31)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:181:17)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:84:5) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
```

bitgo-express:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const { init } = require('../src/expressApp.ts');

if (require.main === module) {
  init()
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(`Fatal error: ${err.message}`);
    console.log(err.stack);
  });
}
```

expressApp.ts:

```
/**
 * @prettier
 */
import * as express from 'express';
import * as httpProxy from 'http-proxy';
import * as url from 'url';
import * as Bluebird from 'bluebird';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import * as debugLib from 'debug';
import * as https from 'https';
import * as http from 'http';
import * as morgan from 'morgan';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { Request as StaticRequest } from 'express-serve-static-core';

import { Config, config } from './config';

const debug = debugLib('bitgo:express');

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/camelcase
import { SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 } from 'constants';
import { IpcError, NodeEnvironmentError, TlsConfigurationError } from './errors';

import { Environments } from 'bitgo';
import { setupRoutes } from './clientRoutes';
const { version } = require('bitgo/package.json');
const pjson = require('../package.json');

const BITGOEXPRESS_USER_AGENT = `BitGoExpress/${pjson.version} BitGoJS/${version}`;

/**
 * Set up the logging middleware provided by morgan
 *
 * @param app
 * @param config
 */
function setupLogging(app: express.Application, config: Config): void {
  // Set up morgan for logging, with optional logging into a file
  let middleware;
  if (config.logFile) {
    // create a write stream (in append mode)
    const accessLogPath = path.resolve(config.logFile);
    const accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(accessLogPath, { flags: 'a' });
    console.log('Log location: ' + accessLogPath);
    // setup the logger
    middleware = morgan('combined', { stream: accessLogStream });
  } else {
    middleware = morgan('combined');
  }

  app.use(middleware);
  morgan.token('remote-user', function(req) {
    return req.isProxy ? 'proxy' : 'local_express';
  });
}

/**
 * If we're running in a custom env, set the appropriate environment URI and network properties
 *
 * @param config
 */
function configureEnvironment(config: Config): void {
  const { customRootUri, customBitcoinNetwork } = config;
  if (customRootUri) {
    Environments['custom'].uri = customRootUri;
  }

  if (customBitcoinNetwork) {
    Environments['custom'].network = customBitcoinNetwork;
  }
}

/**
 * Create and configure the proxy middleware and add it to the app middleware stack
 *
 * @param app bitgo-express Express app
 * @param config
 */
function configureProxy(app: express.Application, config: Config): void {
  const { env, timeout } = config;

  // Mount the proxy middleware
  const options = {
    timeout: timeout,
    proxyTimeout: timeout,
    secure: true,
  };

  if (Environments[env].network === 'testnet') {
    // Need to do this to make supertest agent pass (set rejectUnauthorized to false)
    options.secure = false;
  }

  const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer(options);

  const sendError = (res: http.ServerResponse, status: number, json: object) => {
    res.writeHead(status, {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    });

    res.end(JSON.stringify(json));
  };

  proxy.on('proxyReq', function(proxyReq, req) {
    // Need to rewrite the host, otherwise cross-site protection kicks in
    const parsedUri = url.parse(Environments[env].uri).hostname;
    if (parsedUri) {
      proxyReq.setHeader('host', parsedUri);
    }

    const userAgent = req.headers['user-agent']
      ? BITGOEXPRESS_USER_AGENT + ' ' + req.headers['user-agent']
      : BITGOEXPRESS_USER_AGENT;
    proxyReq.setHeader('User-Agent', userAgent);
  });

  proxy.on('error', (err, _, res) => {
    debug('Proxy server error: ', err);
    sendError(res, 500, {
      error: 'BitGo Express encountered an error while attempting to proxy your request to BitGo. Please try again.',
    });
  });

  proxy.on('econnreset', (err, _, res) => {
    debug('Proxy server connection reset error: ', err);
    sendError(res, 500, {
      error:
        'BitGo Express encountered a connection reset error while attempting to proxy your request to BitGo. Please try again.',
    });
  });

  app.use(function(req: StaticRequest, res: express.Response) {
    if (req.url && (/^\/api\/v[12]\/.*$/.test(req.url) || /^\/oauth\/token.*$/.test(req.url))) {
      req.isProxy = true;
      proxy.web(req, res, { target: Environments[env].uri, changeOrigin: true });
      return;
    }

    // user tried to access a url which is not an api route, do not proxy
    res.status(404).send('bitgo-express can only proxy BitGo API requests');
  });
}

/**
 * Create an HTTP server configured for accepting HTTPS connections
 *
 * @param config application configuration
 * @param app
 * @return {Server}
 */
async function createHttpsServer(
  app: express.Application,
  config: Config & { keyPath: string; crtPath: string }
): Promise<https.Server> {
  const { keyPath, crtPath } = config;
  const privateKeyPromise = fs.promises.readFile(keyPath, 'utf8');
  const certificatePromise = fs.promises.readFile(crtPath, 'utf8');

  const [key, cert] = await Promise.all([privateKeyPromise, certificatePromise]);

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/camelcase
  return https.createServer({ secureOptions: SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1, key, cert }, app);
}

/**
 * Create an HTTP server configured for accepting plain old HTTP connections
 *
 * @param app
 * @return {Server}
 */
function createHttpServer(app: express.Application): http.Server {
  return http.createServer(app);
}

/**
 * Create a startup function which will be run upon server initialization
 *
 * @param config
 * @param baseUri
 * @return {Function}
 */
export function startup(config: Config, baseUri: string): () => void {
  return function() {
    const { env, ipc, customRootUri, customBitcoinNetwork } = config;
    console.log('BitGo-Express running');
    console.log(`Environment: ${env}`);
    if (ipc) {
      console.log(`IPC path: ${ipc}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Base URI: ${baseUri}`);
    }
    if (customRootUri) {
      console.log(`Custom root URI: ${customRootUri}`);
    }
    if (customBitcoinNetwork) {
      console.log(`Custom bitcoin network: ${customBitcoinNetwork}`);
    }
  };
}

/**
 * helper function to determine whether we should run the server over TLS or not
 */
function isTLS(config: Config): config is Config & { keyPath: string; crtPath: string } {
  const { keyPath, crtPath } = config;
  return Boolean(keyPath && crtPath);
}

/**
 * Create either a HTTP or HTTPS server
 * @param config
 * @param app
 * @return {Server}
 */
export async function createServer(config: Config, app: express.Application) {
  return isTLS(config) ? await createHttpsServer(app, config) : createHttpServer(app);
}

/**
 * Create the base URI where the BitGoExpress server will be available once started
 * @return {string}
 */
export function createBaseUri(config: Config): string {
  const { bind, port } = config;
  const tls = isTLS(config);
  const isStandardPort = (port === 80 && !tls) || (port === 443 && tls);
  return `http${tls ? 's' : ''}://${bind}${!isStandardPort ? ':' + port : ''}`;
}

/**
 * Check environment and other preconditions to ensure bitgo-express can start safely
 * @param config
 */
function checkPreconditions(config: Config) {
  const { env, disableEnvCheck, bind, ipc, disableSSL, keyPath, crtPath, customRootUri, customBitcoinNetwork } = config;

  // warn or throw if the NODE_ENV is not production when BITGO_ENV is production - this can leak system info from express
  if (env === 'prod' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    if (!disableEnvCheck) {
      throw new NodeEnvironmentError(
        'NODE_ENV should be set to production when running against prod environment. Use --disableenvcheck if you really want to run in a non-production node configuration.'
      );
    } else {
      console.warn(
        `warning: unsafe NODE_ENV '${process.env.NODE_ENV}'. NODE_ENV must be set to 'production' when running against BitGo production environment.`
      );
    }
  }

  const needsTLS = !ipc && env === 'prod' && bind !== 'localhost' && !disableSSL;

  // make sure keyPath and crtPath are set when running over TLS
  if (needsTLS && !(keyPath && crtPath)) {
    throw new TlsConfigurationError('Must enable TLS when running against prod and listening on external interfaces!');
  }

  if (Boolean(keyPath) !== Boolean(crtPath)) {
    throw new TlsConfigurationError('Must provide both keypath and crtpath when running in TLS mode!');
  }

  if ((customRootUri || customBitcoinNetwork) && env !== 'custom') {
    console.warn(`customRootUri or customBitcoinNetwork is set, but env is '${env}'. Setting env to 'custom'.`);
    config.env = 'custom';
  }
}

export function app(cfg: Config): express.Application {
  debug('app is initializing');

  const app = express();

  setupLogging(app, cfg);

  const { debugNamespace, disableProxy } = cfg;

  // enable specified debug namespaces
  if (_.isArray(debugNamespace)) {
    _.forEach(debugNamespace, ns => debugLib.enable(ns));
  }

  checkPreconditions(cfg);

  // Be more robust about accepting URLs with double slashes
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.url = req.url.replace(/\/\//g, '/');
    next();
  });

  // Decorate the client routes
  setupRoutes(app, cfg);

  configureEnvironment(cfg);

  if (!disableProxy) {
    configureProxy(app, cfg);
  }

  return app;
}

/**
 * Prepare to listen on an IPC (unix domain) socket instead of a normal TCP port.
 * @param ipcSocketFilePath path to file where IPC socket should be created
 */
export async function prepareIpc(ipcSocketFilePath: string) {
  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    throw new IpcError(`IPC option is not supported on platform ${process.platform}`);
  }

  try {
    const stat = fs.statSync(ipcSocketFilePath);
    if (!stat.isSocket()) {
      throw new IpcError('IPC socket is not actually a socket');
    }
    // ipc socket does exist and is indeed a socket. However, the socket cannot already exist prior
    // to being bound since it will be created by express internally when binding. If there's a stale
    // socket from the last run, clean it up before attempting to bind to it again. Arguably, it would
    // be better to do this before exiting, but that gets a bit more complicated when all exit paths
    // need to clean up the socket file correctly.
    fs.unlinkSync(ipcSocketFilePath);
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.code !== 'ENOENT') {
      throw e;
    }
  }
}

export async function init(): Bluebird<void> {
  const cfg = config();
  const expressApp = app(cfg);

  const server = await createServer(cfg, expressApp);

  const { port, bind, ipc } = cfg;
  const baseUri = createBaseUri(cfg);

  if (ipc) {
    await prepareIpc(ipc);
    server.listen(ipc, startup(cfg, baseUri));
  } else {
    server.listen(port, bind, startup(cfg, baseUri));
  }

  server.timeout = 300 * 1000; // 5 minutes
}
```

Node.js version: 12.19.1
NPM version: 6.14.8

How can I fix this issue? I saw this [SyntaxError: Cannot use import statment without a module, TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Catch 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62792310/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statment-without-a-module-typeerror-err-unknown) which was similar to mine. But that answer didn't help me as then I'll have to edit the whole file and even I did I'm stuck in 38 line. If someone can translate the whole code into node friendly require, Please translate it. Much appreciated!

Comment: In order to execute TypeScript, you'll need to compile it first. See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling) (the tutorial's by VS Code but will still work for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your script like this:

```
npx ts-node ./path/to/your-script.ts
```

You may want to build your scripts with typescript compiler and run the build result as ordinary JS script.
But for that you need to setup some bundler like for example [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/) and you need to configure plugins for handling Typescript compilation for example you can use Bable.