# TS ERR_REQUIRE_ESM -> Cannot use import statement outside a module -> ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION -> repeat

Tags: typescript

I've been stuck in an error cycle for hours. I want to have a TypeScript project but each "solution" to each error just moves to another error and it cycles.

It starts with `ERR_REQUIRE_ESM` [so in `tsconfig.json` I change `module` to `es2020`](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb/issues/482). Then I get the error `Cannot use import statement outside a module`, [so in `package.json` I set `type` to `module`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58273824/typescript-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module). Then I'm told `[ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION] Unknown file extension ".ts"` [which I'm told to remove `type` from `package.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63386054/typeerror-err-unknown-file-extension-unknown-file-extension-ts-on-visual-s) and [also being told to set `module` to `commonjs`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1062). The cycle continues, and trying to "just use `nodemon app.ts`" doesn't work as it's same issues except now errors when trying to fiddle with things.

I have no idea what to do, I've followed [guides](https://dev.to/joncodes/how-to-start-a-node-project-from-scratch-with-typescript-3nn9) to get set up and problems start when I try to import or require packages. I've only previously used TypeScript with `create-react-app` before and am used to things just working. I don't know if it is meant to be this much of a pain to just get set up but it's so much extra work and frustration than other languages. Is there just a command like `create-react-app` that just sets up a basic TS project?

Answer (score 2):

so I experienced the same issue but resolved it by using the following settings in the tsconfig:

```json
{
  "ts-node": {
    // these options are overrides used only by ts-node
    // same as the --compilerOptions flag and the TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS environment variable
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs"
    }
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}

Disclaimer: this tsconfig is for a backend project.
For a frontend project, you can add dom and dom.iterable to the lib options and remove the special ts-node compiler options from the tsconfig
```