# ts-node execute typescript with module import and module defined

Tags: typescript, package.json, tsconfig, ts-node

I try to initialize database base via typescript.

my ts is like:

```
import { User, UserRole } from '../entity/User';
import crypto from 'crypto';
import {dbManager, pwhash } from '..';

async function inituser() 
{
    const user = new User();
    user.email = 'sheng.lu@mq.edu.au';
    user.own_organization = []
    user.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    user.password = pwhash("password", user.salt);
    user.role = UserRole.admin;
    await dbManager.save(user);
    const duser = await dbManager.findOne(User);
    return duser;
}
const duser = inituser();

console.log("Loaded users: ", duser);
```

when I try to run the script by ts-node like:

```
npx ts-node db/initializers/inituser.ts
```

there is error for:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1215:27)
    at Module.m._compile (/usr/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:858:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/usr/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:861:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at main (/usr/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:227:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:513:3)
root@MEDAIHILW237:/mnt/c/workgit/projeny# ts-node db/initializers/inituser.ts
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /mnt/c/workgit/projeny/db/initializers/inituser.ts
    at Loader.defaultGetFormat [as _getFormat] (internal/modules/esm/get_format.js:65:15)
    at Loader.getFormat (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:101:42)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:230:31)
    at Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:164:17)
    at Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
root@MEDAIHILW237:/mnt/c/workgit/projeny# ts-node db/initializers/inituser
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /mnt/c/workgit/projeny/db/initializers/inituser.ts
    at Loader.defaultGetFormat [as _getFormat] (internal/modules/esm/get_format.js:65:15)
    at Loader.getFormat (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:101:42)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:230:31)
    at Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:164:17)
    at Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
```

I add "type": "module" in package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "typescript-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
...
}
```

for overcome the error of

```
(node:3854) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Answer (score 41):

The Error `Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or` is caused by the following Bug in ts-node: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/935

The Bug is closed, and there is a proposal to solve it, but it is still open: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1007

I don't need `"type": "module"` in `package.json`.

In `tsconfig.json`, I'm using using `"module": "commonjs"` instead of `"module": "es6",`.

I noted this as technical debt pending that ts-node issue #1007 is resolved.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62096269/cant-run-my-node-js-typescript-project-typeerror-err-unknown-file-extension

Comment: i have had module: "CommonJs", still gives the same error

Comment: I have tried the suggestion still facing this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77330527/typeerror-err-unknown-file-extension-unknown-file-extension-ts-when-using

Answer (score 22):

When ts-node is run inside a project, it uses the local tsconfig.json, which is usually not set up to build for execution.

But you can add a section specifically for ts-node, overriding those settings. Telling it to build for esm works for me:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "nodenext",
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this did not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this helps:

```
node --no-warnings --loader ts-node/esm file.ts
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `-O '{\"module\": \"commonjs\"}'`:

```
npx ts-node -O '{\"module\": \"commonjs\"}' db/initializers/inituser.ts
```

And there is no need to set `"type": "module"` in package.json.

Comment: As explained in the question, the `import * from *`-statement only works with `type: module`. There are some packages (e.g., node-fetch, chalk) which cannot be used without  ESM in their latest version; and so this suggestion won't work for all people suffering from this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
node --import "data:text/javascript,import {register} from 'node:module'; import {pathToFileURL} from 'node:url'; register('ts-node/esm', pathToFileURL('./'))" my-script.ts
```

It works on **Node.js `v20.8.0+`**.

...

You can create a file named `ts-loader.js`:

```js
import {register} from 'node:module'
import {pathToFileURL} from 'node:url'

register('ts-node/esm', pathToFileURL('./'))
```

And then:

```bash
node --import ./ts-loader.js my-script.ts
```

<sup>*Remember: Don't write the loader path as <del>`ts-loader.js`</del> (if loader file is located in your source). But make sure write it with **relative path: `./ts-loader.js`** as you do it in your internal `import`s!*</sup>

### Cons:

1. It **can't resolve w/o extension `import`s** inside `my-script.ts` (and recursively inside files that are imprted in `my-script.ts`)! So all **your `import`s should have explicit `.js` extension** (or possible `.ts` extension if you configure [`allowImportingTsExtensions`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowImportingTsExtensions) in your `tsconfig.json`).
2. Also, you **can't omit `/index.js`/`/index.ts`** from the end of your paths!
3. It **doesn't support `jsx`/`tsx`** contents!
4. As I checked, it doesn't respect your [`compilerOptions.paths` configuration in your `tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths). For example, if you configured something like `"@/*": ["./src/*"]` in your `paths` then the above loader **can't resolve `@/...` prefixed `import`s** inside `my-script.ts` (and inside files imprted directly or inderectly in it)!
5. In very simple cases that I tested, it was about **2x slower** than the below perfect solution using [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/):

---

### Alternative perfect solution using `register()`/`--import` of node.js v20.8+ and [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/):

I wrote this loader-script in my projects:

`register-ts-loader.js`:

```js
// Useful links:  
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/68621282/5318303  
// https://github.com/nodejs/loaders-test/blob/main/typescript-loader/loader.js  
// https://github.com/nodejs/loaders-test/blob/main/commonjs-extension-resolution-loader/loader.js  
  
import {transform} from 'esbuild'  
import {readFile} from 'node:fs/promises'  
import {isBuiltin, register} from 'node:module'  
import {dirname, extname, posix, relative, resolve as resolvePath, sep} from 'node:path'  
import {fileURLToPath, pathToFileURL} from 'node:url'  
  
//  It's probably a good idea to put this loader near the end of the chain.  
register(import.meta.url, pathToFileURL('./')) // Register this file, itself.  
  
// noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols  
export async function resolve(specifier, context, nextResolve) {  
  if (isBuiltin(specifier)) return nextResolve(specifier, context)  
  
  const defaultResolutionTry = nextResolve(specifier, context)  
  const {data: defaultResolutionResult} = await defaultResolutionTry.then(  
    (data) => ({data}),  
    (error) => ({error}), // ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND | ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT | ... (?)  
  )  
  
  // If module found and its format successfully detected use: `defaultResolutionResult`  
  if (defaultResolutionResult && !('format' in defaultResolutionResult && !defaultResolutionResult.format))  
    return defaultResolutionResult  
  
  if (specifier.startsWith('@/')) {  
    specifier =  
      './' +  
      posix.join(  
        toPosix(relative(dirname(fileURLToPath(context.parentURL)), resolvePath('src'))), // TODO: Do this according to project's "tsconfig.json"  
  posix.relative('@', specifier),  
      )  
    // Retry default-resolution with new resolved `specifier`:  
  const defaultResolutionResult = await nextResolve(specifier, context).catch(() => {})  
    // If module found and its format successfully detected use: `defaultResolutionResult`  
  if (defaultResolutionResult && !('format' in defaultResolutionResult && !defaultResolutionResult.format))  
      return defaultResolutionResult  
  }  
  
  const originalExt = extname(specifier)  
  let resolvedExt = ''  
  
  // Let's try to resolve the module:  
  const generalTries = () =>  
    nextResolve(specifier + (resolvedExt = '.js'), context)  
      .catch(() => nextResolve(specifier + (resolvedExt = '.jsx'), context))  
      .catch(() => nextResolve(specifier + (resolvedExt = '.ts'), context))  
      .catch(() => nextResolve(specifier + (resolvedExt = '.tsx'), context))  
      .catch(() => nextResolve(specifier + '/index' + (resolvedExt = '.js'), context))  
      .catch(() => nextResolve(specifier + '/index' + (resolvedExt = '.jsx'), context))  
      .catch(() => nextResolve(specifier + '/index' + (resolvedExt = '.ts'), context))  
      .catch(() => nextResolve(specifier + '/index' + (resolvedExt = '.tsx'), context))  
      .catch(() => defaultResolutionTry) // If our tries to resolve the module failed, return `defaultResolutionTry` promise.  
  
  const nextResolverResult = ['.js', '.jsx'].includes(originalExt)  
    ? // 1. Special case: First replace ".jsx?" extension with ".tsx?":  
  await nextResolve(  
        specifier.slice(0, -originalExt.length) + // Cut ".jsx?"  
  (resolvedExt = originalExt.replace('j', 't')), // Append ".tsx?"  
  context,  
      ).catch(generalTries) // If the above special-try failed, continue to `generalTries` ...  
  : await generalTries() // 2. General cases: Just do `generalTries` ...  
  
  return EXTENSIONS.has(resolvedExt)  
    ? {  
        format: resolvedExt, // Provide a signal to `load()`  
  shortCircuit: true,  
        url: nextResolverResult.url,  
      }  
    : nextResolverResult  
}  
  
// noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols  
export async function load(url, context, nextLoad) {  
  if (context.format === 'json')  
    return {  
      format: 'module',  
      shortCircuit: true,  
      source: `export default ${await readFile(fileURLToPath(url), 'utf-8')}`,  
    }  
  
  const nextLoaderResult = await nextLoad(url, {format: 'module', ...context})  
  
  if (!EXTENSIONS.has(context.format)) return nextLoaderResult  
  
  const rawSource = nextLoaderResult.source.toString()  
  
  const {code: transpiledSource} = await transform(rawSource, {  
    loader: 'tsx', // https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#typescript + https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#jsx  
  sourcemap: 'inline',  
    target: 'esnext',  
  })  
  
  return {  
    format: 'module',  
    shortCircuit: true,  
    source: transpiledSource,  
  }  
}  
  
const EXTENSIONS = new Set(['.jsx', '.tsx', '.ts'])  
  
/** Convert **relative-path** to posix format. */  
const toPosix = (relativePath) => relativePath.replaceAll(sep, posix.sep)
```

And then:

```bash
node --import ./register-ts-loader.js my-script.ts
```

without the above cons.

<sup>*Don't forget `npm i -D esbuild`.

Also, see: https://esbuild.github.io/api/#transform.*</sup>

---

See my other answer about new Node.js features around `--loader` and newer `--import` + `register()`:

[Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import when attempting to start Nodejs App locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64449464/error-err-unsupported-dir-import-directory-import-when-attempting-to-start-no/68621282#68621282)

---

**Alternatively, use [Bun.js](https://bun.sh/)** and enjoy its out of the box TypeScript support and its other features and optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

I think some are answering a different question but for anyone hitting this SO question looking for how to invoke ts-node in VS Code and avoid the deprecation warning as I did:

1. Create a **.js** file as indicated by Mir-Ismaili above.
2. Create/update a launch config in VS Code's launch.json containing a runtimeArgs section similar to the following:

```js
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch in ts-node",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development",
                "DEBUG": "wa_reminders:*",
                "DEBUG_COLORS": "true",
            },
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--import",
                "./src/ts-loader.js"
            ],
            "args": [
                "${relativeFile}"
            ],
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**",
                "<node_modules>/**"
            ],
            "type": "node",
        },
        ...    
    ]
```