# Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import when attempting to start Nodejs App locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, sequelize.js

I'm caught in a bit of a loop trying to deploy my app to Heroku. My import statements (e.g. `import cors from 'cors'`) seem to prevent the app from launching in production, due to the "Cannot Load ES6 Modules in Common JS" error. Locally it runs just fine.

However, when I attempt to resolve the above error by adding `"type": "module"` to my `package.json` I get a whole new set of errors and the app will no longer run locally. I *believe* this error is due to the way I'm initializing sequelize and associated models but I am unsure. I'd like to resolve this error but need a hand with new syntax for the imports... I think.

Error, `package.json` and `index.js` include below.

**Error Text**

```
[nodemon] starting `babel-node src/index.js`
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import '/Users/jeff/Clients/Bummer/Code/Server/src/models' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from /Users/jeff/Clients/Bummer/Code/Server/src/index.js
    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:272:17)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:699:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:810:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:85:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:229:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:51:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:50:36) {
  code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT',
  url: 'file:///Users/jeff/Clients/Bummer/Code/Server/src/models'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**Package.JSON**

```
{
  "name": "bummer",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/node": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "pg": "^8.2.1",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "sequelize": "^6.3.5",
    "sequelize-auto-migrations": "^1.0.3",
    "uuid": "^8.0.0"
  }
}
```

**Index.js**

```
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import models, { sequelize } from './models';
// import routes from './routes';

//Initiaze Express
const app = express();
const routes = require('./routes');


//Helpers for Spotify oAuth
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')


// Include Middleware
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
   .use(cors())
   .use(cookieParser())
   .use(express.json())
   .use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
   require('dotenv').config()

   

// Include all Models
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.context = {
    models,
  };
  next();
});



// Load Routes from Router Index
app.use('/', routes);

sequelize.sync().then(() => {
  app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${process.env.PORT}!`)
  });
});
```

Thoughts or pointers? Thank you!

Comment: where you able to solve this . I have the same issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Node.js, import statements are permitted only in ES modules. so, directory imports do not work in Node.js. Read Node.js [Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_statements).

Comment: I'm not sure this is very helpful - Node.js handles these imports fine when running locally, and just has trouble on Heroku. Maybe some configuration needs to be set on Heroku. Or could you explain why that's not the case?

Answer (score 73):

#### Explicitly, point to your main file (usually `index.js`). E. g.

```js
import ... from './models'          // ❌
import ... from './models/index.js' // ✅
```

---

##### <s>Alternative way</s> (see the below UPDATE for Node.js v19+ and the newer one for Node.js 20.8+):

Use `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` flag. For example:

```bash
node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node main.js
```

See:
https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_customizing_esm_specifier_resolution_algorithm

---

### UPDATE (Node.js v19+):

> Node.js has removed the `--experimental-specifier-resolution` flag. Its functionality can now be achieved via **custom loaders**.

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v19-release-announce/#custom-esm-resolution-adjustments

The simplest **loader** (that only appends `.js` extension if needed) is something like:

```js
import {isBuiltin} from 'node:module'

// noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
export const resolve = (specifier, context, nextResolve) => // This function can be `async` too
  nextResolve(isBuiltin(specifier) || specifier.endsWith('.js') ? specifier : `${specifier}.js`, context)
```

Name it `loader.js` (or `loader.mjs` if you don't set yet `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`).

Then if you run your script (e.g. `./some-script.js`) using this loader:

```bash
node --loader ./loader.js some-script.js
```

the `import`s within `some-script.js` (and the files imported in it) can omit `.js` extension.

See more complex examples: https://github.com/nodejs/loaders-test

---

### UPDATE (Node.js v20.8+): `register()`/`--import`

Using **`register()`** function (from built-in `node:module` package) and then **`--import`** flag (instead of `--loader`).

There is a `ts-loader` example, in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77693896/5318303), using `ts-node/esm` (from [`ts-node` library](https://www.npmjs.com/ts-node)):

> ```js
> import {register} from 'node:module'
> import {pathToFileURL} from 'node:url'
>
> register('ts-node/esm', pathToFileURL('./'))
> ```
>
> And then:
>
> ```bash
> node --import ./ts-loader.js my-script.ts
> ```

That has some cons that I mentioned there (specially in `import`s inside your file/files).

Plus **another perfect ts-loader solution using [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io)** that you can see it [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77693896/5318303).

They're both originally for executing TypeScript files using Node.js. But **they both work for the purpose of current question, too**. It means you can execute your `models/index.js` (or `models/index.ts`), by:

```bash
node --import ./ts-loader.js models
```

or (using [the second perfect solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77693896/5318303)):

```bash
node --import ./register-ts-loader.js models
```

Also, using it, you can execute `js`/`ts` files **w/o extension** + **running `ts` files with `js` extension** (as you can `import` `ts` files in another `ts` file, using `js` extension). With [the second perfect solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77693896/5318303), you can enjoy these features recursively for `import`s inside your file/files. Plus supporting `jsx`/`tsx`!

Comment: Thanks! Using `node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node` worked great!

Answer (score 7):

Try adding the `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` flag to your `start` script in `package.json`, particularly if you're using this flag when running locally - this is the script Heroku will use to start your server.

```
scripts": {
    "start": "node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node index",
    ...
},
```

Comment: This solved for me! And if the App is a CLI Application, include `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` in the shebang after `node`

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this code in `package.json`

```js
"scripts": {
  "start": "node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node src/index"
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Option 1
"type": "module",
should come before "main":

Option: 2
Update source file to .mjs extension

Comment: This solution will still throw the error when importing directories

Comment: This doesn't work