# Import module without file extension such as ".js", ".ts", ".d.ts" using ES6 syntax in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm going to develop my backend using node.js and typescript.
But I faced serious problem - importing modules using ES6 import syntax.

I import constant variables like below code:
`import { PORT } from "./config";`

But this throws an error:

```
Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import 'D:\app\server\dist\config' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from D:\app\server\dist\index.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:319:17)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:945:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT',
  url: 'file:///D:/app/server/dist/config'
}
```

So I can solve this problem with following code:
`import { PORT } from "./config/index.js";`

But I want to import module like this: `import { PORT } from "./config";`

How can I do?

There are some code:

```
// src/config/index.ts
export const PORT: number = 4000;
```

```
// src/index.ts
...
import { PORT } from "./config";    // this line throws error!
...
```

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDirs": ["src"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "ignoreDeprecations": "5.0"
  }
}
```

```
//package.json
{
  ...
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc",
    "start": "npm run compile && node ./dist/index.js",
    "dev": "powershell -Command \"$env:NODE_OPTIONS='--loader ts-node/esm'; npx nodemon src/index.ts\""
  },
  ...
}
```

I want to import module using ES6 import syntax in typescript without any file extension such as ".js", ".ts", and ".d.ts". I also don't want to use Babel.

Comment: Directory imports are *not* supported. You _must_ target `index.js`. The only workaround is a feature called "import maps", which you could take a look at. I would not recommend it though, best to keep things simple reduce magic.

Comment: try running it with `tsx` (ts runner), it should work with everything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error \[ERR\_UNSUPPORTED\_DIR\_IMPORT\]: Directory import when attempting to start Nodejs App locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64449464/error-err-unsupported-dir-import-directory-import-when-attempting-to-start-no)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But this answer is not helpful to me. I get another error: Cannot find package '@apollo/server.js' imported from D:\app\server\dist\index.js.
I think the solution is fit to js but not ts.