# Can't run a TS node + ES app - either get `ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION ` or `new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND`

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

I'm trying to compile my code as ES code (using `"type": "module"` inside package.json and `"module": "esnext"` inside tsconfig.json).

I can't run it using any of the 3 approaches below:

1. `ts-node src/server.ts` results in:

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/dbricks/mvp/server/src/server.ts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:363:5)
    at Loader.defaultGetFormat [as _getFormat] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:71:15)
    at Loader.getFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:105:42)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:243:31)
    at Loader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:177:17)
    at Object.loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:68:5)
```

Which from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62096269/cant-run-my-node-js-typescript-project-typeerror-err-unknown-file-extension) seems to be a problem with ts-node.

2. So I try `node --loader ts-node/esm ./src/server.ts` and get this:

```
(node:45543) ExperimentalWarning: --experimental-loader is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/dbricks/mvp/server/node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-esm-resolve-implementation.js:383
    throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(
          ^
CustomError: Cannot find module '/Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/dbricks/mvp/server/src/app' imported from /Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/dbricks/mvp/server/src/server.ts
    at finalizeResolution (/Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/dbricks/mvp/server/node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-esm-resolve-implementation.js:383:11)
    at moduleResolve (/Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/dbricks/mvp/server/node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-esm-resolve-implementation.js:818:10)
    at Object.defaultResolve (/Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/dbricks/mvp/server/node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-esm-resolve-implementation.js:929:11)
    at /Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/dbricks/mvp/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:68:38
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/dbricks/mvp/server/node_modules/ts-node/dist/esm.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/dbricks/mvp/server/node_modules/ts-node/dist/esm.js:4:12)
    at resolve (/Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/dbricks/mvp/server/node_modules/ts-node/dist/esm.js:32:16)
    at Loader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:89:40)
```

But src/app.ts is clearly sitting there in the folder!

3. So I tried compiling first with `tsc` and then running `node --loader ts-node/esm ./dist/src/server.js`. I get pretty much the same error as (2), except this time it's `/Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/dbricks/mvp/server/dist/src/app` that's missing. Which also makes no sense, since I can see it in the folder.

How do I solve this? I've read every thread on stack overflow and I'm out of options. Why is running an ES node app so hard?

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue, and I wanted to keep all files in typescript. I saw the answer provided by @BlueFrog but instead of converting the module imports to `.js`, I used this experimental flage instead:

```sh
node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm myScript.ts
```

It works successfully.

More info [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1007)

Answer (score 2):

Came across the same issue. Fixed by following [this ts-node issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1007).

---

TL;DR
Just add the `.js` extension to your module imports and run ts-node with `node --loader ts-node/esm src/index.ts`