# Cannot get the absolute paths working in typescript nodejs project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to setup a simple typescript, node environment with absolute paths instead of relative paths.

I followed the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKz7rnbQyK4): but can't get the absolute imports to resolve properly when I run `npm run start:dev`. The VSCode intellisense is able to resolve the absolute import paths fine, but when I compile, I get compilation error.

Note: relative paths are compiling and working fine. But absolute paths are giving compilation error.

Here's my **.nvmrc**:

```
v16.15.1
```

Here is my code structure:

[image]

Here's my simple code:

**src/index.ts:**

```javascript
import add from '@src/math/add';

console.log(add(2, 1));
```

Here `@src/math/add` is giving compilation error. `./math/add` compiles fine.

**src/math/add.ts:**

```js
import force from '@src/science/physics';
const add = (a: number, b: number): number => {
  console.log(`force:${force(5, 3)}`);
  return a + b;
};
export default add;
```

Here `@src/science/physics` is giving compilation error. `../science/physics` compiles fine.

**src/physics/force.ts:**

```js
const force = (mass: number, accelaration: number): number => mass * accelaration;

export default force;
```

Here is my **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"],
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "coverage"],
  "include": ["src"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "lib": ["DOM", "ESNext"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,


    /* JavaScript Support */
    "allowJs": true,

    /* Emit */
    "outDir": "dist",
    "removeComments": true,

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,

    /* Modules */
    "module": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "." /*meaning wherever is this tsconfig.json file, that is the root directory*/,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["src/*"]
    },

    /* Interop Constraints */
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

    /* Completeness */
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Here is my **package.json**:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "name": "express-proj-setup-tut",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/index.ts",
    "start:prod": "node -r ts-node/register/transpile-only -r tsconfig-paths/register ./dist/src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.7.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.33.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.33.1",
    "eslint": "^8.22.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.4.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

Finally, here's the error message in terminal:

[image]

I would greatly appreciate if someone can help me out getting the absolute paths working.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to solve your issue with your configuration of module in package.json and module in tsconfig.json but if you remove `"type": "module"` from package.json and change to `"module": "CommonJS"` in your tsconfig.json you will be able to run `"start:dev": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/index.ts"`.

For me output was

```
force:15
3
```

Related question: [Can't run my Node.js Typescript project TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /app/src/App.ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62096269/cant-run-my-node-js-typescript-project-typeerror-err-unknown-file-extension)

Comment: thank you for your comment. Yes, I had got it working with ""module":"CommonJS" but anything that requires "type":"module" in package.json (like ES2015,  ES2020) does not compile with absolute paths. Glad to know that I am not the only one with this issue. VSCode intellisense resolves it just fine. So most likely the issue is in the "start:dev": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/index.ts",

Answer (score 0):

Check if your node.js version is higher than 14.6.0

Having `./src` folder with ts code, `./dist` folder as tsc output folder write following to map `./src` as `#root` global path:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "#root/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

```json
// package.json
{
  ...
  "imports": {
    "#root/*": "./dist/*"
  },
}
```

Such aliases should start with `#` symbol.

Useful links:

- https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-imports
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths

Comment: @Meoster thank you for the answer.
rootDir is configured to be same as where tsconfig.json is located, hence ".". same for baseUrl. With those settings, the VSCode intellisense is able to pickup the imported modules and show it on mouse-hover. Also, I am not transpiling it to javascript, as am using ts-node in dev environment. Hence ./dist folder is not generated when running in dev. Do you think the error is in the "start:dev": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/index.ts" in package.json?

Answer (score -1):

In your tsconfig.json, you need change

```json
"paths": {
      "@src/*": ["src/*"]
    },
```

for this:

```json
"paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
```

And in include, you need add all paths that include ts files, like this:

```json
"include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
```

I hope that solve that compilation error :-)

Comment: thank you for your reply. I did as you suggested. The error stays. The weird thing is that eslint is able to resolve it fine in VSCode. The compiler is having trouble.