# Build express server with webpack typescript and esm

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, es6-modules

I'm trying to build a small project `node.js + ts` using `webpack`.

```
tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ESNext"],
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "rootDir": "./"
  },
}
```

I added it to the `package.json` line `"type": "module"`

```
webpack.config.ts
import * as path         from 'path';
import * as webpack      from 'webpack';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

const PATHS = {
  entry:  path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/server/index.ts'),
  output: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
};

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
  target:  'node',
  entry:   PATHS.entry,
  output:  {
    path:     PATHS.output,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module:  {
    rules: [
      {
        test:    /\.ts(x?)$/,
        use:     'ts-loader',
        exclude: '/node_modules/',
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  },
};

export default config;
```

By running the  command `"build": "webpack --config config/webpack.config.ts --mode development"`, I get an error :

> [webpack-cli] Failed to load
> '/node_esm/webpack.config.ts' config
> [webpack-cli] TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file
> extension ".ts" for
> /node_esm/webpack.config.ts

I tried adding to my `config.json` `"ts-node": { "esm": true}` this didn't help solve my problem. What do I need to do in order to build an application using webpack?

- node: v16.18.1
- ts-loader: v9.4.2
- typescript: v4.9.4
- webpack: v5.75.0
- webpack-cli: 5.0.1

**UPD**
I've tried change tsconfig.The first option is to open your tsconfig.json file and look for compilerOptions. Set target to "ES5" and module to "CommonJS" (or completely remove the module option).

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "rootDir": "./"
  }
}
```

the error remained the same.
The second option is to add settings for ts-node:

You can keep "module": "ESNext" for tsc, and if you use webpack, or another build tool, set an override for ts-node.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "rootDir": "./"
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "CommonJS"
    }
  }
}
```

also at this point I tried to add

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext" // or ES2015, ES2020
  },
  "ts-node": {
    // Tell ts-node CLI to install the --loader automatically, explained below
    "esm": true
  }
}
```

as stated in the typescript documentation.
The third option is to install the tsconfig-paths package it also didn't help.in all cases, the error remained the same as it was written before.

```
package.json
{
  "name": "node_esm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --config config/webpack.config.ts --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --config config/webpack.config.ts --mode development"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.15",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "@types/webpack": "^5.28.0",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^5.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.2",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to start the webpack build with `ts-node`. Did you read https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-languages/#typescript?

Comment: @morganney yes, I tried to do as it is written in the documentation, but it didn't help.

Comment: How are you starting the webpack build?

Comment: @morganney I wrote the command how I run webpack in question.

Comment: Then you don't read documentation clearly. You're not using `ts-node`.

Comment: @morganney what is it about? I might have missed something in the documentation. I tried specifying ts-node in tsconfig.

Comment: @Phil yes, im intsall all deps. I tried all 3 options, the error remained the same

Comment: @Phil Of course I tried them separately

Comment: Thanks for updating. The error you're seeing is from `ts-node`. See [Can't run my Node.js Typescript project TypeError \[ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION\]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /app/src/App.ts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62096269/283366). At this stage I'd be weighing up how useful Webpack is for this project. You could also save _some_ pain and just use JS for the Webpack config

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a web bundler to build your server-side app?

Comment: Not trying to troll, but why put yourself through this pain? I've managed an in-house Webpack app for years and I'm happy to say that I will never do it again. Webpack is intended for libraries and not so much applications.

I suggest something like Next.js or Create React App.

Comment: can you pls provide the code repo or create a reproducible code base?

Comment: @eezing OP's title says _"Build express server"_. The question isn't even tagged with [tag:reactjs]. Laughably, both Next.js and Create React App also build on Webpack so it's not clear at all where you're going with your comment about libraries

Comment: @Phil "Webpack is intended for libraries and not so much applications." Looks like I wrongly assumed the OP's intended use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is that Webpack uses the `ts-node` API, not the CLI so you need to configure the node loader appropriately.

I got it working using the following configuration.

`package.json`

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "NODE_OPTIONS='--loader ts-node/esm' webpack --mode development"
},
```

See the ts-node documentation on [Native ECMAScript modules](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#native-ecmascript-modules)...

> If you are not using our CLI, pass the loader flag to node.

You may want to use something like [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) or [env-cmd](https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd) if you plan on building this on Windows.

---

Note: I didn't need anything special in `tsconfig.json`. No `ts-node` section is required since that only applies to the CLI.

---

Aaaaand, I just found [this troubleshooting guide](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#typeerror-err_unknown_file_extension-unknown-file-extension-ts-for-webpackconfigts) in the Webpack CLI reference

> #### TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for ./webpack.config.ts
>
> You might encounter this error in the case of using native ESM in TypeScript (i.e. type: "module" in package.json).
>
> webpack-cli supports configuration in both CommonJS and ESM format, at first it tries to load a configuration using require(), once it fails with an error code of 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM' (a special code for this case) it would try to load the configuration using import(). However, the import() method won't work with ts-node without loader hooks enabled (described at TypeStrong/ts-node#1007).
>
> To fix the error above use the following command:
>
> ```sh
> NODE_OPTIONS="--loader ts-node/esm" npx webpack --entry ./src/index.js --mode production
> ```

The SEO on that page must be terrible. Hopefully linking it here helps boost it a little.