# Typescript Error when running npm start in index.mts

Tags: javascript, typescript

No matter what I do I keep gettig some type of error in my index.mts file in typescript.

```
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".mts" for /Users/CMO/Desktop/ts-course/l09-final/index.mts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:99:9)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:139:38)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:83:20)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:319:26)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:194:22)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:63:26)
    at #createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:218:17)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.getJobFromResolveResult (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:171:34)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:156:17) {   code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION' }
```

Node.js v20.0.0

Heres my package.json

```
{
    "name": "final-project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Testing TypeScript code",
    "main": "index.mts",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "tsc && node index.mts"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "randomstring": "^1.2.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/randomstring": "^1.1.8",
        "typescript": "^5.0.4"
    }
}
```

Comment: `node index.mjs`?

Comment: this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62096269/cant-run-my-node-js-typescript-project-typeerror-err-unknown-file-extension

Comment: Why do you use `mts`extension instead of `ts`?

Answer (score -1):

Check your node version. If you have followed everything that is suggested on this link: [Can't run my Node.js Typescript project TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /app/src/App.ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62096269/cant-run-my-node-js-typescript-project-typeerror-err-unknown-file-extension), then i would try downgrading your node version.

I was running on 20.2.0 and tried everything suggested there. A colleague tried it on their machine running 19.8.1 version and it worked. After i downgraded, i was able to pass this step.