# Typescript files are not recognized by the sharding manager

Tags: typescript, discord.js, sharding

I'm trying to configure the shard system in my bot, developed in TypeScript, however, when I configure the main file, discord.js itself does not recognize the file written in ts.

Here's the error:

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for C:\Users\.\Documents\Programação\Discord\Pessoal\Tom5\Tom5#v6\src\bot.ts
```

The launcher.ts file (responsible for creating the shards):

```
import chalk from "chalk";
import { ShardingManager } from "discord.js";

export class ShardsManager extends ShardingManager {
    constructor() {
        super(
            "src/bot.ts",
            {
                token: "", //I've been putting the bot's token here
                respawn: true,
                totalShards: "auto",
            }
        )

        this.on("shardCreate", (shard) => {
            console.log(
                chalk.bold.green(
                    `[SHARD - ${shard.id + 1}]`
                ),
                "Criada"
            )
        })

        this.spawn()
    }
}


new ShardsManager()
```

The main file (bot.ts):

```
import chalk from "chalk";
import Tom5 from "./classes/Tom5";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv"
dotenv.config()

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
    console.log(
        chalk.bold.red(
            "[SCRIPT REJEITADO]\n"
        ),
        reason
    )
});

process.on("uncaughtException", (err, origin) => {
    console.log(
        chalk.bold.red(
            "[ERRO CAPTURADO]\n"
        ),
        err
    )
})

process.on('uncaughtExceptionMonitor', (err, origin) => {
    console.log(
        chalk.bold.red(
            "[SCRIPT BLOQUEADO]\n"
        ),
        err
    )
});

await new Tom5().init()
```

Best regards,
TomG

I tried to rename the file to `bot.js`, however, it caused multiples unnecessary errors, especially importing typescript files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't run my Node.js Typescript project TypeError \[ERR\_UNKNOWN\_FILE\_EXTENSION\]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /app/src/App.ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62096269/cant-run-my-node-js-typescript-project-typeerror-err-unknown-file-extension)

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros No, it is all like they suggested.

Comment: Are you using ts-node?

Comment: @GodderE2D yes. Is it causing this?