# How to register an ESM loader from application code in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules

I am writing a heredoc script that is evaluated as an ESM module, but I'm running into the [`ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62096269/cant-run-my-node-js-typescript-project-typeerror-err-unknown-file-extension) error, because my script is importing raw TS sources.

I don't have control over the command to ensure `node --loader ts-node/esm` option is passed to configure the [ESM loader](https://github.com/nodejs/loaders), so I would like to find a way to register it from my script at runtime.

I do have `ts-node` available in the environment, so I'd like to do something similar to how I would register `ts-node` in CJS:

```
require('ts-node/register')
require('./typescript-module')
```