Fastest way to run typescript files
Background
From this repo I'm running a typescript program
node --loader ts-node/esm ./examples/ts/cli.ts bitget fetchBalance

The typescript version of the program a lot longer than the comparable js version of the program
node --loader ts-node/esm ./examples/ts/cli.ts   bitget fetchBalance  14.73s user 0.60s system 153% cpu 10.010 total
node                      ./examples/js/cli.js   bitget fetchBalance  0.49s  user 0.07s system 14%  cpu 3.756  total

I'd like to reduce the amount of time that this program takes to run and one of the first things that I'm looking at is the method in which I am running typescript

tsx
tsx was working for me earlier, but after running a git reset --hard I get the error below, even after installing jsbn


% tsx ./examples/ts/cli.ts bitget fetchBalance
node:internal/errors:484
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/.../ccxt/ts/src/static_dependencies/jsencrypt/lib/jsbn/jsbn.js' imported from /.../ccxt/ts/src/static_dependencies/jsencrypt/lib/jsrsasign/asn1-1.0.js
    at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (node:internal/errors:484:5)
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:323:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:916:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1124:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at d (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/tsx/dist/esm/index.mjs:5:34)
    at O (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/tsx/dist/esm/index.mjs:5:1162)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:841:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v18.12.0



ts-node
When I try ts-node I get the following error
 % ts-node ./examples/ts/cli.ts bitget fetchBalance
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /.../ccxt/examples/ts/cli.ts

Solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62099904/6331353
problem with solution 1
I cannot remove "type": "module", from package.json because then I receive the error
import fs from 'fs';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

problem with solution 2
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  }

is already in my tsconfig.json

these problems happen when I use ts-node or ts-node-esm

ts-node-esm
When I try to use ts-node-esm, I get


 %  ts-node-esm ./examples/ts/cli.ts bitget fetchBalance        
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
ts/src/base/Exchange.ts:1141:43 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DOMException'.

1141                         this.AbortError = DOMException
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~
ts/src/base/Exchange.ts:1148:44 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'self'.

1148                 this.fetchImplementation = self.fetch
                                                ~~~~
ts/src/base/Exchange.ts:1149:35 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DOMException'.

1149                 this.AbortError = DOMException
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~

    at createTSError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859:12)
    at reportTSError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:863:19)
    at getOutput (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1077:36)
    at Object.compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1433:41)
    at transformSource (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:400:37)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:278:53
    at async addShortCircuitFlag (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:409:15)
    at async nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:22)
    at async ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:605:20)
    at async ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:457:11) {
  diagnosticCodes: [ 2304, 2304, 2304 ]
}




Have you tried bun?

There is another tsconfig here https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/master/examples/tsconfig.json which is the active one when you compile something in examples. That doesn't have DOM in the lib array but looks like it should. If there are perf issues use the swc option https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/swc/.

Or deno, if security or V8 compatibility is important...

Since while using node --loader ts-node/esm you are compiling, the process takes time indeed. 14s is still a lot in my opinion, but it could make sense. In order to avoid the entire compilation to be run every time you need to change the file, you should consider using  a watch flag. If you don't need to make changes to the file, then, probably you should use the js file since it runs faster.

What takes time is the transpilation, type checking, module resolution and so, not he run itself. Incremental builds could be an option, but since you are using ts-node or similar, the transpiled files are stored in memory. I'm sorry but I can't really help you more without details of your use case.

So is your question how to fix your tsx error? What exactly are you asking for? Are you simply trying to get people to create bitget accounts or what? You're a member of https://github.com/ccxt so shouldn't you have other resources besides stackoverflow?


SWC (Speedy Web Compiler)
Steps to use SWC:

Install SWC:
npm install --save-dev @swc/cli

Transpile the TypeScript file:
swc your-file.ts --outfile output.js

Run the generated JavaScript file:
node output.js



esbuild
Steps to use esbuild:

Install esbuild:
npm install --save-dev esbuild

Run the TypeScript file with esbuild:
npx esbuild --bundle --platform=node your-file.ts



esbuild-runner
Steps to use esbuild-runner:

Install esbuild and esbuild-runner:
npm install --save-dev esbuild esbuild-runner

Run the TypeScript file:
node -r esbuild-runner/register your-file.ts



