# Repl.it Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script

Tags: javascript, html, replit

```js
import myJson from './usage.json';
function pyRun(file, input) {
    console.log('b');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: `${file}.py`,
        data: { param: input },
    }).done(() => {
            console.log('a');
            console.log(myJson.test);
        });
}

function clicked(){
    console.log('c');
    pyRun('test', 'input');
}

document.getElementById("sendBtn").addEventListener("click", clicked());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Open Aternos Server!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="User name">
    <input type="text" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
  <button id="sendBtn">Start</button>
  <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my html and js code and here also json:

```
{
"name": "",
"pass": "",
"info": "",
"succes": "",
"test": ""
}
```

and also python:

```
print("runing nice!")
uFile = open("usage.json", "w")
json_object = json.load(uFile)
json_object["test"] = "test"
json.dump(json_object, uFile)
uFile.close()
```

and when I run it on repl.it gives the error: "Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/json". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec." I don't know why that's happening I search it on web but in codes they are using server hosts I am not using an host and because of this I don't know why this happens and also if I have any wrong thing in other parts of code please also say them because I can't run code with this error so I can't see the result thanks already(I use console.log('a') or console.log('c') like things to understand what part is wrong but console was empty there was only error I mention above)

Comment: Here's another answer regarding REPL and importing ES Modules: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54784608/how-to-import-an-es-module-in-node-js-repl -- Have you read through this one?

Comment: Also, this whole section on nodejs.org is packed with caveats. https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#json-modules (as well as https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions)