# getting error trying to import object into mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to import an object into a mongoose schema, but I am getting an 'unexpected identifier' error. Am I making a syntax error or not, I am not sure how to export.

my exported object

```
const electronic = {
    title: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },
    price: { type: String },
    location: { type: String },
    image: { type: Array },
    phone: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        ref: 'User'
    }
}

export default electronic
```

where I import the object

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
import electronic from '../master_objects/electronics'

const electronics = new mongoose.Schema(
    electronic, {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('vancouver_electronic', electronics);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intead of doing `export default electronic` ,do `module.exports=electronic`
for more info [Getting Unexpected Token Export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296667/getting-unexpected-token-export)