# Node.js - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to learn Node.js server side and trying to come to grips on how to use it.

I keep getting an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'"

I have installed Node.js on visual studio npm, installed common.js and express.js

my package.json

```
{
"name": "test3",
"version": "1.0.0",
"private": true,
"description": "test program",
"main": "index.js",
"dependencies": {
"common-js": "^0.3.8",
"express": "^4.17.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
"@babel/register": "^7.9.0"
},
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"type": "module",
"author": "xxx",
"license": "ISC"
 }
```

Not sure why im getting this error, if tried everything.

All i want to do is make a request to the action method in mvc controller.
This is the app.js

```
'use strict';

define(function (require) {
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(57743);
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/AddSubscribe', sayHello);
});
```

Full error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
require.js:5 Uncaught Error: Module name "@babel/register" has not been loaded yet for context: _. 
Use require([])
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
at makeError (require.js:5)
at Object.s [as require] (require.js:5)
at requirejs (require.js:5)
at start.js:1
require.js:5 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (exports, $, Popper) { 
 'use strict';

 $ = $ && $.hasOwnProperty('default') ? $['default'] : $;
 Popper = Popper && Popper.hasOwnProperty('default') ? Popper['default'] : Popper;

function _defineProperties(target, props) {
for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
  var descriptor = props[i];
  descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false;
  descriptor.configurable = true;
  if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true;
  Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor);
}
}

 function _createClass(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
if (protoProps) _defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
if (staticProps) _defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
return Constructor;
 }

 function _defineProperty(obj, key, value) {
if (key in obj) {
  Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
    value: value,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true
  });
} else {
  obj[key] = value;
}

return obj;
}

function ownKeys(object, enumerableOnly) {
var keys = Object.keys(object);

if (Object.getOwnPropertySymbols) {
  var symbols = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(object);
  if (enumerableOnly) symbols = symbols.filter(function (sym) {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, sym).enumerable;
  });
  keys.push.apply(keys, symbols);
}

return keys;
} 

function _objectSpread2(target) {
for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
  var source = arguments[i] != null ? arguments[i] : {};

  if (i % 2) {
    ownKeys(Object(source), true).forEach(function (key) {
      _defineProperty(target, key, source[key]);
    });
  } else if (Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors) {
    Object.defineProperties(target, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(source));
  } else {
    ownKeys(Object(source)).forEach(function (key) {
      Object.defineProperty(target, key, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, key));
    });
  }
 }

return target;
}

function _inheritsLoose(subClass, superClass) {
subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass.prototype);
subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass;
subClass.__proto__ = superClass;
}


 var TRANSITION_END = 'transitionend';
 var MAX_UID = 1000000;
 var MILLISECONDS_MULTIPLIER = 1000; 

 function toType(obj) {
return {}.toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-z]+)/i)[1].toLowerCase();
}

 function getSpecialTransitionEndEvent() {
return {
  bindType: TRANSITION_END,
  delegateType: TRANSITION_END,
  handle: function handle(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is(this)) {
      return event.handleObj.handler.apply(this, arguments); // eslint-disable-line prefer-rest-params
    }

    return undefined; // eslint-disable-line no-undefined
  }
};
}

 function transitionEndEmulator(duration) {
var _this = this;

var called = false;
$(this).one(Util.TRANSITION_END, function () {
  called = true;
});
setTimeout(function () {
  if (!called) {
    Util.triggerTransitionEnd(_this);
  }
}, duration);
return this;
}

function setTransitionEndSupport() {
$.fn.emulateTransitionEnd = transitionEndEmulator;
$.event.special[Util.TRANSITION_END] = getSpecialTransitionEndEvent();
}



var Util = {
TRANSITION_END: 'bsTransitionEnd',
getUID: function getUID(prefix) {
  do {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-bitwise
    prefix += ~~(Math.random() * MAX_UID); // "~~" acts like a faster Math.floor() here
  } while (document.getElementById(prefix));

  return prefix;
},
getSelectorFromElement: function getSelectorFromElement(element) {
  var selector = element.getAttribute('data-target');

  if (!selector || selector === '#') {
    var hrefAttr = element.getAttribute('href');
    selector = hrefAttr && hrefAttr !== '#' ? hrefAttr.trim() : '';
  }

  try {
    return document.querySelector(selector) ? selector : null;
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
},
getTransitionDurationFromElement: function getTransrequire.js:5)
at T (require.js:5)
at require.js:5
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult AddSubscribe(string name, string email, string message, int? sub)
    {



        return Json(new { success = "success"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Unexpected Token Export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296667/getting-unexpected-token-export)

Comment: No it does not i already looked at that resource

Comment: what node version are you using ? Can you post your full code ? i cant repoduce the error, also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example