# accessing app.getAppPath("temp") from another file

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an src/starter.js file

that has

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
```

etc that creates in the app window.

In src/another.js file I am trying to get the `app.getAppPath("temp")` path. I've tried `export app` `export { app }`, `export const tempPath = app.getAppPath("temp")` and importing those in the another.js file but nothing seems to work. How should I be able access these from another.js file?

Comment: if you export anything not related to the app, does it work?
in other words: app needs initialization, it might not have the info yet or maybe you aren't exporting/importing correctly

Comment: are you using ES modules? have you tried `module.exports = { app }` then importing it via `const { app } = require('./otherfile')`? If you're using webpack/babel you should just be able to do `import { app } from 'electron'`

Comment: The app initialises fine, and creates the window etc. If I try to export I get 'unexpected token export', or if I try those from KFE then the app still initialises but then all the UI is gone and I get 'Uncaught TypeError: r.existsSync is not a function' from index.js

Comment: given your error I'd take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296667/getting-unexpected-token-export