# Are there any obvious reasons why my import isn't working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a simple module export import in `node.js`.

Here's js.js:

```
let animal = "cat";

export {animal};
```

Here's js2.js:

```
import {animal} from './js.js';
console.log(animal);
```

This is my error message:
[image]

This is where the files are located:
[image]

Comment: did you tried without extension .js ?

Comment: Are you sure that JS file is loaded and executed as a _module_? Try `.jsm` or `.mjs` instead of `.js`.

Comment: @user4642212 Tried that and didn't make a difference. This article (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) would seem to suggest `.js` will suffice

Comment: @sonEtLumiere were you suggesting that I rename them to `js` and `js2`? Tried that and didn't work

Comment: import {animal} from './js'; (without the .js extension, only the file name)

Comment: I think this suggests to use a different syntax instead (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296667/getting-unexpected-token-export)

Comment: @murrayju Then you would have to use `import animal` instead of `import {animal}`.

Comment: @Barmar you are thinking of `export default animal`