# JavaScript import {func1, func2, func3} from functions.js causing "Unxepected token '{'

Tags: javascript, import, export

I have a small web app and I have now decided to tidy it up a bit and separate out the functions into a functions.js file.

I'm exporting these and importing these in the main.js file however I'm getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'.

I'm defining it in the index.html

```
<head>
  <script type = "module" src="functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type = "module" src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

functions.js

```
export function hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
export function hello2() {
        return "Hello";
    }
```

Main.js

```
import { hello, hello2 } from 'functions.js';
```

However when I run this using "Static-Server" I'm getting the error mentioned above.
I'm not sure why this is happening as the code look ok?

Comment: @RandyCasburn - I neglected to show but I have
`<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type = "module" src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>`

Question updated with relevant info

Comment: Here is what it should look like: http://plnkr.co/edit/zxWxmR5dZ7EUrnsN - you only need one script tag that brings in your root module. Then, in your import statement, you'll need an absolute or relative path to `functions.js` - the easiest way to do that is to use `./functions.js`

Comment: @RandyCasburn - I have done that and still the same issue `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'` in the Main.js file where I import {hello}.

Comment: The plunkr works...right? How are you running your project or loading your HTML file?

Comment: @RandyCasburn- I'm running Static-Server via node.js as there all local files

Comment: well let's do this - put your content into a plunkr just like I did - then we'll see what's going on.

Comment: Are you using any kind of bundler or code parsing tools like Webpack or Grunt or Gulp on your web site before you launch it with "static-server" ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using nodejs. It requires CommonJS Module syntax. That means

```
export function hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
```

becomes

```
module.exports = function hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
```

same with `import`

Please find more information here, especially the third answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60615051/4912528

Comment: The OP is _not_ using NodeJS to execute the javascript files. He's loading ES6 modules from the `<head>` of an HTML file.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thats the second problem, yes :D But his described error message comes from an environment that requies CommonJS syntax. (as you see in his last comment, he is indeed using nodejs as a server)

Comment: I edited my comment. The OP is _not_ using NodeJS to execute the javascript files. He's loading ES6 modules from the `<head>` of an HTML file. That file is indeed loaded from an HTTP server that is run using NodeJS.

Comment: You may very well be correct, we'll need to see what the OP provides in the form of a Plunkr.

Comment: Ping - just FYI so you are aware of OPs self-provided answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exporting like this:

```
export function hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
export function hello2() {
        return "Hello";
    }
```

Change it to :

```
 function hello() {
            return "Hello";
        }
     function hello2() {
            return "Hello";
        }

export default {hello, hello2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what was wrong. I was wrapping my code in

```
$(function(){
import {hello, hello2} from './functions.js'
}
```

to help with document load race conditions.
instead I needed to move the import above this

```
import {hello, hello2} from './functions.js'
$(function(){

}
```

Comment: Please consider the next time you ask a question you provide the actual code in your project - _NOT_ the code **you think you need to provide**. That was a 10sec fix if you would have just shared your **_actual_** code!