# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module when importing axios

Tags: node.js, express, axios

In my node.js (express.js) project, I try to wrap axios to create a HttpClient like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const httpClient = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://locahost:3003' });

...

export const httpClient = {
       ...
  };
```

When I run it, I get error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` which complains the line `import axios from 'axios'`. How can I get rid of this error?  (I come from React-native world, I used the same thing in React-Native, it is fine)

Comment: How did you use this module? More information needed. And one thing. You can not define `httpClient` constant and after do `export const httpClient = .....`

Comment: I found the answer I am looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296667/getting-unexpected-token-export

Answer (score 1):

The issue is by default express uses CJS format of importing as you might have seen `const axios = require("axios")`.

What you are trying to do is an ESM format of import which is not understood by the JS as natively. To work import statements you can either add the following property to your package.json file  - `"type": "module"` or you can use "*.mjs" extension instead of default "*.js" extension.

Hope this [link](https://thecodebarbarian.com/nodejs-12-imports) helps further.

Comment: Thanks but I wonder Is there anyway resolve the issue by modifying my code? I mean I am looking for a suggestion to just modify my current code to eliminate the error instead of either changing extension or adding the `"type":"module"`

Comment: There is no other method of doing it that I know of