# Electron: Problem to import my own .js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, electron

I'm discovering Electron and I'm facing a problem: I can't implement my **"common.js"** file in my **"test.js"** script.

Here is the architecture of my project:

```
rootProject
   -features(folder)
      -common.js
      -test.js
   -index.html
```

**common.js**

```
const hello = "hello";
module.exports = { hello };
```

**test.js**

```
const {hello} = require("./common.js");
console.log(hello);
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <span id="timeAfterRefreshGasFees"></span>
    <span id="rapid"></span>
    <span id="fast"></span>
    <span id="standard"></span>
    <span id="slow"></span>
  </div>
  <!-- You can also require other files to run in this process -->
  <script src="./renderer.js"></script>

  <!-- <script src="./features/common.js"></script> -->
  <script src="./features/test.js"></script>
</body>
```

In this case, I got: ***Error: Cannot find module './common.js'***

And if I uncomment **<script** in **index.html**, I got this error: ***Identifier 'hello' has already been declared***

I want to have a **common.js** file where I can put stuff inside (like const etc...)

How can I fix it?

I already tried all these solution: [Getting Unexpected Token Export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296667/getting-unexpected-token-export)

Thank you!

**EDIT after first solution:**

I added these lines to get nodeIntegration

```
webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration: true,
  contextIsolation: false,
  preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
}
```

And removed **<script** in **common.js**

```
<script  src="./features/common.js"></script>
```

But now, I have this error when I'm trying to **require** in **test.js**:
**Cannot find module './common.js'**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the require() not existing in the client-side javacript

An answer more developed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059825/11224089

Answer (score 1):

Like @brunocordioli072 said `require` is only a Node.js function, and by default Node.js functions are disabled in Electron.

Because this is Javascript you can use `<script>` tags like you're doing to include files.

> And if I uncomment <script in index.html, I got this error: Identifier 'hello' has already been declared

This is because `hello` is already defined in `common.js` and because your including `common.js` with a `<script>` tag you can already use it inside `test.js` without using `require`.

---

Side note:

If you really need to use `require` or other Node.js functions you can simply turn on `nodeIntegration` and turn off `contextIsolation` in your BrowserWindow settings like this:

```js
new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences:  {
        nodeIntegration:  true,
        contextIsolation: false
    },
});
```

However this will create [security problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59888788/6577664) in your app.

Comment: Ok! Thank you for your answer. I understood I can call a function/var without his class if I'm using <script> integration. But I need to use "require" to implement npm package. So with "nodeIntegration:true" I got this error: "Cannot find module './common.js'". Check the original post

Comment: If you turn on `nodeIntegration` like you've done you can use `require` to import NPM modules, but not files, so `require('./common.js')` still won't work. So add your `<script>` tag back in and now that `nodeIntegration` is turned on you can do things like: `require('fs')`