# migrate target from es5 to es6 in browser and test runner

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, ecmascript-5

I have some code in typescript

- DTMEdge.ts
- DTMNode.ts
- DTreeMap.ts

resulting after compilation in

- wwwroot

  - js

    - dtree

      - DTMEdge.js
      - DTMNode.js
      - DTreeMap.js

basically each ts file looks like

```
export class DTxxx {
    ....
}
```

DTreeMap.ts starts with

```
import { DTMEdge } from "./DTMEdge";
import { DTMNode } from "./DTMNode";
```

with `"target": "es5"` in tsconfig.json I can:

- use the resulting code in a browser by importing it via

```html
    <script src="/js/dtree/DTMEdge.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dtree/DTMNode.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dtree/DTreeMap.js"></script>
```

- run test with mocha, the test file begining with:

```js
    const assert = require('assert');
    const { DTMEdge} = require('../wwwroot/js/dtree/DTMEdge.js');
    const { DTMNode } = require('../wwwroot/js/dtree/DTMNode.js');
    const { DTreeMap } = require('../wwwroot/js/dtree/DTreeMap.js');
```

when I switch to `"target": "es6"`  in tsconfig.json I can:

- use the resulting code in a browser by importing it via

```html
<script type="module">
    import {DTMNode} from "./js/dtree/DTMNode.js"
    import {DTMEdge} from "./js/dtree/DTMEdge.js"
    import {DTreeMap} from "./js/dtree/DTreeMap.js"
```

But I can't run my test with the following error:

```
...\wwwroot\js\dtree\DTMEdge.js:1
export class DTMEdge {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
...
```

How can'I get my tests run when I target es6 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Unexpected Token Export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296667/getting-unexpected-token-export)

Comment: @gunwin renaming every file to .mjs inclufing the test file and importing with `import { DTMEdge } from '../wwwroot/js/dtree/DTMEdge.mjs';`, I insist on the {} solves the problem. BUT, I now loose the ability to use the Visual Studio Test Explorer. I had to dig into the doc to see if I can specify a file extention csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is:

- rename test file as .mjs
- copy each file to filename.mjs
- edit test script accordingly:

```js
import { DTMEdge } from '../wwwroot/js/dtree/DTMEdge.mjs';
import { DTMNode } from '../wwwroot/js/dtree/DTMNode.mjs';
import { DTreeMap }  from '../wwwroot/js/dtree/DTreeMap.mjs';
```

- edit package.json

```json
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --recursive './tests/*.*js'"
  }
```

et voilà:

> npm test

runs.