# Typescript Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having trouble figuring out what this error means but i'm sure it can be resolved with another "easy hack"..... As everything lately to do with web tech stacks seems to be fixed with another little "easy hack".......

Getting this error for some dumb reason i'm sure.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
>
> at app.js:2
>
> (anonymous) @ app.js:2

all i did was export a function to test typescript out.

> core/CoreTest.ts

```
export function testFunction () : void {

console.log("This is a core test");

}
```

and then i called it here...

> app.ts

```
import { testFunction } from './core/CoreTest.js';

testFunction();
```

Comment: Checkout this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/60615051/3473281.

Comment: @samthomas doesn't seem relevant

Comment: @Phil Tried that. i get a compilation error.

Comment: @Phil Sorry. should of included in the last comment. that i tried omitting the extension as well. And this also did not work for me.

Comment: What version of NodeJS are you running. I just tried locally with your exact files (omitting the extension in the import) and running `npx ts-node app.ts` prints _"This is a core test"_. Node 14.17, TS 4.5.4

Comment: Try creating [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the issue in a sandbox like https://codesandbox.io/ and paste the link into your question. Because other than the file extension on your import, nothing appears obviously wrong.

Comment: @Phil I'm not using node.js. I'm simply just trying to use Typescript for front end web development that will be hosted by an apache server. This is my first time trying to use typescript for front end development, just trying to test it out.

Comment: @AlexWayne I wasn't familiar with codesandbox.io so it took me while.... My code worked there no problem. so my guess is that there must be some magical configuration setting I'm missing with my compiler...... a proper error would be nice.....

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-leftpad-0i4ip?file=/tsconfig.json

Comment: What is the contents of your tsconfig.json? How does it compare to the one in that sandbox?

Comment: @Kunikos how are you running your app? Typescript doesn't directly run the browser, you need to compile it to JS first and that's usually done via a Node environment

Answer (score 1):

posted this question around on multiple sites. to the credit of this individual i was able to fix my problem.
https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/s5vqpj/uncaught_referenceerror_exports_is_not_defined/ht0s9x4/?context=3

**Solution**
change from commonjs to es6 in tsconfig.json

"module": "commonjs"

"module": "es6"