SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' show after reload
showing some errors on x-chart after reload
in this code show errors and i am not able to solve this error anything solve this error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
import { BarChart } from '@mui/x-charts/BarChart';

<BarChart
      series={[
        { data: [35, 44, 24, 34] },
        { data: [51, 6, 49, 30] },
        { data: [15, 25, 30, 50] },
        { data: [60, 50, 15, 25] },
      ]}
      height={290}
      xAxis={[{ data: ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'], scaleType: 'band' }]}
      margin={{ top: 10, bottom: 30, left: 40, right: 10 }}
    />


Refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296667/getting-unexpected-token-export. Which version of NodeJS are you utilizing?
